# Python Broadcasting: how to unleash NumPy speed when filling in a One-Hot vector?

Tags: python, numpy, array-broadcasting

In order to use tensorflow, I need a one hot vector for my classes.

I have the following code to create a one-hot vector, but it seems like it should be ripe for numpy broadcasting.

```
def classVector2oneHot(classVector):
    uniques = np.asarray(list(set(classVector)))
    one_hot_array = np.zeros(shape=(classVector.shape[0],uniques.shape[0]),dtype=np.float32)

    starting_index = np.min(uniques)

    # where broadcasting seems like it should be possible, somehow...
    for i in range(len(one_hot_array)):
        one_hot_array[i,classVector[i]-starting_index] = 1



    return one_hot_array
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one approach using  [`broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) -

```
(classVector[:,None] == uniques).astype(float)
```

Sample run -

```
In [47]: classVector
Out[47]: array([15, 16, 24, 20, 14, 12, 14, 19, 12, 21])

In [48]: uniques = np.unique(classVector)

In [49]: uniques
Out[49]: array([12, 14, 15, 16, 19, 20, 21, 24])

In [50]: (classVector[:,None] == uniques).astype(float)
Out[50]: 
array([[ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.]])
```